# How to inherit from Javascript Date Object?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create and object that inherits from the Date object.

Below is a Firebug transcript of what I am trying to do.

```
>>> date_son = Object.create( Date )
Function {}
>>> typeof date_son
"object"
>>> date_son.gettime
undefined
>>> date_son.prototype.getTime
getTime()
```

I use Object.create to create an object date_son which inherits from Date. The getTime function/attribute is available on  date_son.protype, but not on the date_son object itself.

I am clearly doing something wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to create an object that inherits from Date so that date_son.getTime() is available on the date_son object.

I do not wish to extend Date directly, because I think messing/changing globals is bad programming practice.

Comment: Javascript is case-sensitive. You are contrasting `date_son.gettime` with `date_son.prototype.getTime`; notice the difference in capitalization.

Comment: It'll still be `undefined` because `Date` is a `Function` object, not a `Date` object.

Comment: You can extend from `Date.prototype` instead, and that will give you the methods, but I don't know what good that will do you, because they won't be operating on a Date object when you invoke them.

Comment: Or better yet, extend `new Date()`, but of course you run into the same problems.

Answer (score 2):

There is a note on the MDN Docs by Mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> Note: Note that Date objects can only be instantiated by calling Date or using it as a constructor; unlike other JavaScript object types, Date objects have no literal syntax.

`Object.create` expects an instance when a parameter is given. `Date` is no instance on its own and will therefore not work with Object.create.

Furthermore, to address your issue with extending Date directly:

Extending native objects is something which is done regularly. MooTools does it for instance with their own `.implement` method:

https://github.com/mootools/mootools-more/blob/master/Source/Types/Date.js#L55

Tutorial about extending natives:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-how-to-extend-built-in-objects-in-javascript/

**Edit**:

And an article about the presumed evils of extending natives: http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/

Comment: `Object.create` does not expect an object literal; it expects an instance of any object. For example, `Object.create([1, 2, 3])` works fine, as does `var x = [1, 2, 3]; Object.create(x)` or `Object.create(new Number(3))`.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my post accordingly. Had literal and instance mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
var date_son = Object.create( Date.prototype );
```

but it wouldn't seem to do much good because you'll be calling those methods on something other than a `Date`.

```
console.log( date_son.getTime() );  // won't work
```

---

You could call it like this, but I don't know why you'd want to:

```
var date_son = Object.create( Date.prototype );

var new_date = new Date();

console.log( date_son.getTime.call( new_date ) );  // 1313964470748
```

---

If you want to add some Date utilities, and you don't want to extend `Date.prototype`, then just create a library of methods that accept a `Date` object.

```
var date_son = {
    some_method: function( d ) {
        // do something with the date
        return d;
    }
};

var date = date_son.some_method( new Date );
```

Comment: @Raynos: I just really like seeing my avatar! Actually, my original answer simply offered the `var date_son = Object.create( Date.prototype );` solution without giving consideration to whether it was a useful solution. It allowed access to the methods, but they were useless for what I assume OP intends.

Answer (score 1):

Good news! This works with the new class-based syntax introduced in ES5.

```
class DateSon extends Date {
    equals(other) {
        if (typeof other === "object") {
            return this.getTime() === other.getTime();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    copy() {
        return new Date(this.getTime());
    }
}

dateSon1 = new DateSon();
dateSon2 = dateSon1.copy();
dateSon2.setDate(dateSon1.getDate() + 1);

console.log(dateSon1.equals(dateSon2));
```