# Accessing Date object's methods via prototype in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, class, methods, prototype

I'm trying to inherit/gain access to all the properties/methods of the Date object by using prototype of my getTime object, but I'm missing something. Point me in the right direction please.

```
//empty constructor 
function getTime(){}

//attempt to inherit all of the properties and methods of Date object
getTime.prototype = new Date();

//create a new Date object and test
//this works
var wt = new Date();
alert(wt);

//create a new getTime object and test.
//I was uner the impression that getTime object 
//now has access to all the properties/methods of the Date object.
//'This generates:TypeError this is not a Date object.'
var wt2 = new getTime();
alert(wt2.getHours());
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nysteve/QHumL/12/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extend the Javascript Date object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075231/how-to-extend-the-javascript-date-object)

Comment: Reading that thread, it looks like there is no way to inherit a Date object. One of the answers there were to create a Date object inside another object/class. Although that would get me the result, I needed this specific approach. Side note; how does one delete a question with answers even if they are the author? In this case since it's a dupe, no need for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to the Date object's prototype is actually working but those methods expect to deal with a object of type Date. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141488/2847629

Answer (score 0):

I think your `getTime`-constructed object *does* have access to all the properties/methods of the Date object. If it didn't, the error would be something like `getHours is not a function` (because it would be undefined).

I’m not sure how the Date object’s `getHours` method is implemented, but JavaScript does have a `hasOwnProperty` method. If the Date object was something you’d implemented in JavaScript, you could write its `getHours` method to check whether the object it’s called on (which, in your example, would be `wt2`) had a property defined on itself (rather than on its prototype object).

The Date objects’s `getHours` method might be doing something like that.